# How to get Cookies Stored In Browser Using Node Js in FrontEnd (React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cookies

I tried With js-cookie, but i Got Object not the Actual Cookie.

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
 let username = Cookies.get("id");
 console.log(username)
```

[object object]  ===> Like this I got Output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Node JS in the front end. You're probably using a bundler (such as Webpack) that supports e.g. the `import _ from _` syntax. The browser uses "browser JavaScript", which means you can use the regular [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

As for `js-cookie` not finding your cookie, first validate whether your cookie is even set and accessible from JS in the first place.

Comment: i didn't uploaded the whole code, all is perfect and cookie is present. Anyway i Resolved my issue, in server i did HTTP : True , Instead it should be HTTP : False While Setting Cookie.

Comment: That's what I meant with "validate whether your cookie is even set and **accessible from JS**"

Comment: I Have one more issue now, I hosted my MERN APP on Heroku and Netlify But when i Signin  it Login successfully To Home PAge and Then Redirects Back To Signin Page. I checked what's wrong i found that Cookies are not stored, But all things Work Fine In Locally.